# What is the scaling or order of molecular dynamics (MD) simulations?

Tags: reference-request, simulation, molecular-dynamics

Often in computational science, we talk about the scaling or order of a particular method ($\mathcal{O}(N)$, $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$, $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$, etc.).

I am having a really difficult time finding a resource (book, journal article, or website) that gives an order $\mathcal{O}$ (with respect to $N$, the number of particles) for molecular dynamics (MD) simulations.  Can you please help me?  Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the size of each type of atom is fixed, for a given level of accuracy the asymptotic cost is dominated by far field electrostatic interactions.  These are $O(n)$ using multigrid and $O(n \log n)$ using FFTs.  Thus the optimal complexity is $O(n)$ per time step as a function of the number of atoms simulated.  The time step is also asymptotically constant, so the total complexity of simulating $n$ particles for time $t$ is $O(nt)$.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know of any references that would explain this?

Comment: The first few of these might help: http://www.deshawresearch.com/publications.html.  In particular the first Ewald paper.

Comment: But the factor hidden in the $O$ can be huge, as it contains a factor for the number of local interactions that must be computed for each molecule.

Comment: Yes, the constant factor is $O(L^3/R^3)$, where $L$ is the length scale of near field electrostatics and $R$ is the radius of atoms.